# Given polynomial $P(x+1) = x^3 - 3x + k$, find remainder of $P(3-x)$ when divided by $x+1$

Tags: polynomials

A polynomial problem for 10 grade student.

$P(x+1) = x^3 - 3x + k$. The remainder of $P(x+1) / (x-2)$ is $4$. What is the remainder of $P(3-x) / (x+1)$

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is Your  attempt?

Comment: hint: $8-6+k=4$

Comment: @Vasya, that's incorrect because $p(2+1)=4$

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya: no, we divide $Q(x)=x^3-3x+k$ by $x-2$. It does not matter that it's called $P(x+1)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$p(x+1)=q(x+1)(x-2)+4\implies p(3)=4\implies 4=3^3-9+k\implies k=-14$$
$$p(3-x)=(3-x)^3-3(3-x)-14$$

---

Indeed, by long polynomial division we obtain the remainder is $38$

Comment: Thank you for the response.  As far as, I understand k must be equal to 2 and the overall answer must be equal to 20 (remainder of final division)

Comment: @user1155710  Then check this:https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x%2B1%29%5E3-3%28x%2B1%29-14%29%2F%28x-2%29